# Is it possible to install Joi validate in browser (front end) without babeling?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compilation, babeljs, joi

I am using Angular 1.x and my project in front end is based on ES5 and mix of ES6 features, for example - I am using `let` and I am using `arrow functions` but I wont use `imports` or bundled compiled version of my app.

Since, it easier to develop without the compilation methodology.

However I read that I can install Joi on browser only as babeled:
https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser

Maybe I can have some external js link resource - just like installing Angular 1.x or jQuery or BootStrap - for Joi validation?

I need just the validation package - not the whole Joi framework.

I hope it is reachable atime.

Thanks.